# Swiping from left to right with viewpager and navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-viewpager, touch-event, navigation-drawer

I have a viewpager and a navigation drawer. Both do an action on a horizontal swipe, but how can I control which one is in charge of the swipe action?

My viewpager:

```
Fragment[] allPictures = new Fragment[getNrPictures()];
APicturePageAdapter adapter = new APicturePageAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), allPictures);
vP = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.picPage);
vP.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Via swiping from right to left I can browse through the pictures. Works fine.
Then I added a navigation drawer:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/PicturePageContentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        .......
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_ll"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
               ... content
            </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Opening and closing the drawer works fine, everything seems to be working. However, when I touch the drawer and swipe to the left I want the drawer to close itself and not the viewpager to flip to the previous picture. How can I control who is in charge of the onTouch event?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know is use of droidux library.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0HNMK8xewE

Comment: It's a nice tutorial. But he's NOT using a viewpager, and that's the problem. The viewpager takes precedence on the swipe action.